# Keyboard shortcut to access desktop on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10

Does there exists a keyboard shortcut to access desktop on ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: <super>d or <ctrl><super>d?

Comment: Yup that does it!  For me it's the windows key and d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> should "show desktop" (<kbd>Super</kbd> is usually the key with Windows logo).

Also view [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/useful-shortcut-keys-in-ubuntu/) page which lists all the shortcut keys.

As there are so many, here is a quick selection...

[image]

Comment: @pomsky done...

Comment: Still it was not answering the actual question.

Comment: @pomsky Your guidance is much appreciated.